# HTTPRIO Delphi SOAP Server error 'expects "text/xml"'

Tags: delphi, soap

We have an existing ISAPI DLL compiled in Delphi XE5 which validates customer login. Recently we re-compiled the dll using Delphi DX (10.1 Berlin) and found that the test client, using HTTPRIO, throws the following exception:

> Ex: ESOAPHTTPException: Received content of invalid Content-Type
>   setting: text/html - SOAP expects "text/xml".

We were not able to fix the problem and had to revert back to using Delphi XE5 to amend and re-compile the DLL.

I was wondering if anybody else had a similar problem with SOAP servers.

Comment: What does the actual server response look like? SOAP uses XML, a SOAP server should not be returning HTML

Comment: I am not able to see the response, only the exception as noted above.

Comment: is a packet sniffer, like Wireshark or Fiddler, to see the response data. But the problem is obvious, the server is not delivering XML when it is supposed to be.